# In Excel, I want to extract text before a certain character on some cells but not everyone

Tags: microsoft-excel

My list has the following

```
Ted
Ted~Brianna
Ted
Stacie
Ryan~Brennan
```

I want to extract only the first name, but not all my cells have multiple names. Can anyone help PLEASE?

Comment: are the names really separated by `~` or is that supposed to be a space?

Comment: Do you want to extract a name from every cell or just the first name if a cell has two?

Answer (score 5):

This formula will do it.

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("~",A1&"~")-1)
```

If your cells are in A1 through A5, paste the above in B1. then copy (or drag) it into B2 through B5. Adjust the `A1` parts of the above formula if your cell arrangement is different.

The formula looks for the `~` character in A1. (We add a `~` to the end, to avoid the case of not finding the `~`.) The `LEFT` function then returns the characters up to, but not including, the `~`.